How to insert a newline in auto insert?
I have this code in my .emacs to insert export options when I create an .org file:
;; code for auto-insert-alist
(setq auto-insert-directory "~/template/")
 (setq auto-insert-alist '(
                          ;; templates for python and html mode
                          ;; are examples
                          ;; (python-mode   . "python.template")
                          ;; (html-mode     . "html.template")
                          (org-mode      . "org.template")

                          ;; more such pairs for other modes
                          ;; can be added here...
              ))
(setq auto-insert-query nil)

 (add-hook 'find-file-hook 'auto-insert)   

This is the first line in every .org file I create:
#+SETUPFILE: ~/.emacs.d/org-templates/level-2.org

How do I add 2 new lines so that the cursor is not on this line?
I naively added (newline) on ~template/org.template but that just adds (newline) literally.
Edit-14 Nov 24
Relevant code in my .emacs
(auto-insert-mode t)
(eval-after-load 'autoinsert
  '(define-auto-insert
     '("\\.\\org\\'" . "org skeleton")
     '(""
       "#+SETUPFILE: ~/.emacs.d/org-templates/level-2.org" \n \n \n
       )))


Just add them to the template file org.template (go to the end and press a couple of RETs). Am I missing something?

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

I have this line in ~template/org.template: #+SETUPFILE: ~/.emacs.d/org-templates/level-2.org Adding RET's didn't help. Am I in the wrong template file?

@NickD Ok, I see, you are right, the two lines are added but the cursor is not moved there. How do I move the cursor?

Did you see @nega's answer? That's the way to go if you want to automate it. Personally, I would just do M-> or even arrow down a couple of times.

I see you saw @nega's answer :-) I hadn't scrolled down enough to see the tick.

@NickD I guess @nega did not see my comment. Let me ask you too. The skeleton solution was working fine but now when I create a new org file it started to ask me to confirm: Perform org skeleton auto-insertion? (y or n) How can I get rid of this? I'd like auto insert for every new org file. I added the code in my .emacs to my question. Thanks

See my comment below the answer.

Have you tried a "Skeleton"? Instead of a just a plain-text file, Skeletons (see here, here, and here here in the Autotyping section of the Emacs manual) provide you a certain level automation with your inserted text.
Based on your input, you'd put something like this in your init file.
(auto-insert-mode t)
(eval-after-load 'autoinsert
  '(define-auto-insert
     '("\\.\\org\\'" . "org skeleton")
     '(""
       "#+SETUPFILE: ~/.emacs.d/org-templates/level-2.org" \n \n \n
       )))

Note the three newline markers (\n). This inserts your text, a blank line, and sets the point (cursor) to the line after that looking like:

There are some great examples at AutoInsertMode in the Emacs Wiki that maybe helpful.

Great, thanks. This works fine.

This was working fine but now when I create a new org file it started to ask me to confirm: Perform org skeleton auto-insertion? (y or n) How can I get rid of this? I'd like auto insert for every new org file. I added the code in my .emacs to my question: Thanks

If auto-insert-query is nil, then that question is not asked. Make sure that it is nil globally: use Customize for that, not setq. If e.g. you setq in your init fil and later on your customizations are enabled, you might end up with the customized value. Use C-h v auto-insert-query to inquire about the value.

@NickD Thank you. Works fine now.
